# Fastest/correct way to iterate over NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

What would be the fastest way to iterate over an array? Using a `for` loop is known to be slower, such as:

```
>>> for element in the_array: do thing
```

However, I have an array of size `(N, 7, 2)` and I need to do something with each element `N`. Sometimes this can be a vectorized calculation, so I know there is a fast solution there; sometimes its writing to file though. So my immediate solution is to iterate over a Python `range` and index the array:

```
>>> for i in range(N): file.write(str(list(map(list, the_array[i]))))
```

Is there a faster way (or perhaps, a correct way if this is wrong) to iterate over the array?

Comment: The fastest way is to not iterate.  But usually it isn't the 'iteration' mechanism that's slow, it's the pythonic thing you do each time - like a file write. The fast numpy stuff iterates - but in compiled code

Comment: Have you looked `the_array.tolist()`?

Comment: @hpaulj So if I needed to do a file write for each element, range iteration and indexing is best? Whereas using vectorized functions for N-elements is best elsewhere?

Comment: @hpaulj Converting to the array to a Python `list` caps system memory for the machines and the data sets being used. So keeping memory low is top priority, where speed optimizations can be made is the next.

Comment: Looks like you are writing a str representation of N (7,2) arrays to the file.  Or rather writing N str.  `for roe in thr_array: write(str(row,tolist()))`

Comment: Correct, I am writing a string representation of N (7, 2) arrays to file. Isn't `for row in the_array:` fairly slow due to the overhead of the Python memory allocator and garbage collector creating and destroying IDs for the views of the array?

Comment: Not any worse than the `arr[i]` step.  But feel free to test the alternatives.  I'm recommending `arr.tolist()` because it's faster than `list(arr)` (at least in cases that I've tested).

Answer (score 0):

Make a sample

```
In [290]: arr = np.ones((1000,7,2),int)
```

some simple iterations:

```
In [303]: timeit list(arr)                                                                       
247 µs ± 1.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [304]: timeit [row for row in arr]                                                            
287 µs ± 12.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [305]: timeit [arr[i] for i in range(arr.shape[0])]                                           
325 µs ± 1.65 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

convert the array to completely to list:

```
In [306]: timeit arr.tolist()                                                                    
657 µs ± 30.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [307]: timeit [row.tolist() for row in arr]                                                   
876 µs ± 3.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

move that conversion out of the timing, and just iterate on the resulting list:

```
In [308]: %%timeit alist = arr.tolist() 
     ...: [row for row in alist]                                                                                        
36.9 µs ± 1.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Iteration on a 1000 element list is much faster than iterate on the first dimension of the array.  The array iteration has to make a new array at each step, which is (relatively) slow, even if it is a `view`.  The list iteration just has to reference the list element, which already exists in memory.

Now add string formatting to the task:

```
In [309]: timeit [str(row.tolist()) for row in arr]                                              
3.87 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)                                                                                        
In [310]: timeit [str(row) for row in arr.tolist()]                                              
3.77 ms ± 275 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [311]: timeit [str(arr[i].tolist()) for i in range(1000)]                                     
4.07 ms ± 62.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [312]: %%timeit alist = arr.tolist() 
     ...: [str(row) for row in alist]                                                                                        
3 ms ± 185 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

There's a big jump in time, to the point that it starts swamping the iteration differences.  I expect that with a file write on top of that, the iteration differences will almost disappear.